# A method to return 3 formats of data

Tags: java

I have Date in this format 2009-09-17T00:00:00.000-35:00 . As per the business Rules for my Application , i have written 3 Methods which will accept this Date and returns the Date in  MM/yyyy , yyyyMM and dd .

For example one method  is shown below MM/yyyy

```
private String getMonthYear(String date) throws Exception {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
        String s1 = date;
        String s2 = null;
        Date d;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(s1);
            s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy")).format(d);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s2;
    }
```

Similarly  i have other two methods which will return data in yyyyMM and dd formats ??

This works fine , but does not look good

My question is can we have only one utility which satisfies my requirement ??

Comment: Did you find an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is can we have only one utility which satisfies my requirement ??

I think you're going about this the wrong way to start with. Fundamentally the data is just *a date*. You can apply formats later, when you need to. I suggest you start using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and make your method return a [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html). That captures all the real information, and you can then have three separate [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) objects used to format the value whenever you want.

Wherever you can, represent data using a type which most naturally represents the real information. Get your data into that natural format as early as possible, and keep it in that format until you *have* to convert it into something else (such as a string).

Answer (score 2):

You could define a single method and receive as a parameter the string with the expected date format, the three strings with the formats could be defined as constants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could group the three methods together, and use an additional argument (an enum, for example) to specify which kind of output format you want. But I would not do that. Your solution is cleaner. Why do you think it doesn't look good?

What I would do, however, is transforming the String to a Date once and for all, and using a Date everywhere rather than the String, and transforming the Date with one of your 3 methods (which would take a Date as argument rather than a String) when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a Date class which has the three methods. Like below:

```
public class MyDate {

    private String date = null;

    public MyDate(String date) { 
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getMonthYear() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getYearMonth() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can format the String into three different Strings in the constructor and just return those strings on method calls. That implementation would be good if you make numberous/repeated calls on the same date string. Or you could format the string in the method call, if you are doing it once but if you are doing it once you may want to make the class/methods static and get rid of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library already has utility methods to do this for you.
For example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
///
// first, convert the string to a date object
Date parsedDate = DateUtils.parseDate("2012-05-25T16:10:30.000", 
                                      new String[] {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"});

// now, format the date object to a string, using different formats
String formattedDate = DateFormatUtils.format(parsedDate, "MM/yyyy");
String formattedDate2 = DateFormatUtils.format(parsedDate, "yyyyMM");
```

Take a look at [DateFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateFormatUtils.html) and [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) for more information.